# Subdivision modifier working on part of mesh in Cycles, but not the rest

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subdivision-surface

In this Blend file of a fire extinguisher I am making, the subdivision modifier is working like expected on the tank, and the top of the tank, but when I tried to add the handle, in Cycles it seems like the handle is not being rendered correctly and looks blocky, not sure whats going on. Any help greatly appreciated.

Strange thing is, if I go into wire-frame mode, in the viewport it is showing all of the added geometry and in solid mode it looks how it should, but when rendered it is blocky.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "blocky"  ?

Comment: If I do a render with the current camera view, it looks ok, could you please show a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick responses. I actually seem to have fixed it. I got frustrated and removed the subdivision modifier and then added it again and now its rendering just fine. Anyone know why that would happen? Also, is removing a subdivision modifier and adding another one bad in any way for my mesh?

Comment: Iagree with @moonboots, maybe right click > shade smooth will bring satisfaction.

Comment: I'll try that next time I run into that problem. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: edit: yes it might be what Edmond says, when you shade smooth an object but join another one to it (ctrl J), the new mesh won't be smoothed and you need to redo a shade smooth, I don't why it's necessary though

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a bug, since (1) your file doesn't show any problems and (2) readding the subdivision surface modifier with the same settings has a different (correct) result. Keep in mind that Blender 2.8 isn't released yet. If it would be possible to reproduce the error, please report it to the bugtracker.

Comment: Can be closed. I can't reliably recreate the problem even though it does still happen infrequently. Reapplying subdivision seems to fix it.